# Getting error: "Missing ) after argument list. (line 11, file "Code")

Tags: google-sheets, gmail

I'm new to coding. I am attempting to import e-mail addresses from a Google Sheet to my gmail account. Any help on why this code is not working would be greatly appreciated! Here is the code I have entered:

```
function myFunction() {
  var alreadyAdded = "Already added";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 396; // Number of rows to process

  // Fetch the range of cells A2:F397
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 400

    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for
    var
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
  };
  var row = data[i];
  var lastName = row[0]
  var firstName = row[1]
  var emailAddress = row[2]
  var address = row[3]
  var notes = row[4]

  if (addedAlready != alreadyAdded) {
    // Create contact in Google Contacts
    var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(firstName, lastName, emailAddress);

    // Add values to new contact
    contact.addAddress(address, "");
    contact.setNotes(notes);
    sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue(alreadyAdded);
  };
};


}
```

Comment: Is there a 'goof' in the code? ... around line 11, there is a `for`, then `var`, then another `for` and then a `};` after the loop ???

Comment: When running the code it gives me the error: Missing ) after argument list. (line 11, file "Code")...how should I revise this?

Answer (score 0):

try it var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 400);